# Passing protobuf between Android Activity

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I have a `ListView` that look at a list of my `protobuf` object. When the user click on an item in the `ListView`, I want to show the details of that object. Currently, I am implementing this as a separate activity. Before I start the activity, I need to pass in the object data.

Should I serialize my `protobuf` object and pass it in the child activity? The child activity will have to deserialize the `protobuf` object.

Or should I provide some kind of accessor for my child activity to modify private fields of the parent activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I serialize my protobuf object and pass it in the child activity? The child activity will have to deserialize the protobuf object.

Yeah this is the way to go, :) ... or you can use [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html). Another option is to [extend the Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/68805) and have it store the `protobuf` data. This data will be accessible in all of your Activities.

> Or should I provide some kind of accessor for my child activity to modify private fields of the parent activity?

No this is a bad idea